# Different prices for multiple countries in PrestaShop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to set up a store in PrestaShop 1.6 where the prices are different for every delivery country.
Could someone point me to the correct approach of setting such a request?

My current idea is to set up for each country a new shop in MultiStore, but having 107 countries is too time-consuming. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create multistore. Probably some of the shipping options are the same (in terms of price). You can create custom zone (e.g., Western Europe, Eastern Europe...) and then set price rule.

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Carriers

> Creating a New Carrier using the Carrier Wizard In this section, we
>   are going to create a complete carrier, from A to Z, using the Carrier
>   Wizard. You can create as many carriers as you wish. If one carrier
>   has different shipping services, you should create as many carriers in
>   PrestaShop, and differentiate them with their names: Many of the
>   details asked by PrestaShop's forms should be provided by your
>   carriers once you have set up an account or are under contract with
>   them directly. Check with them in order to make sure everything is
>   configured correctly. To create a new carrier, click on the "Add new"
>   button in the "Carriers" page. This will open the Carrier Wizard on
>   the first of its four panels.
>
> Panel 2: Shipping locations and costs 
>   [image: enter image descriptionhere]

**"Shipping locations and costs" is the place where you can use your custom zone. It will appear automatically based on your settings.**

http://nemops.com/prestashop-shipping-zones-countries/#.VaQ4-RvtlBc

Comment: Thank you, this is one of the best solutions ever!

Comment: The best solution with score "-1" :D.

Comment: if you have a better solution please say it. Many of us can be mean, but not all have a solution ;)